# How to put an int back into an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
    // This code lets the computer select the first random number from your array
  int rn1 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
    System.out.println("Computer's Value: " + rn1);

    // This code lets the computer select the second random number from your array      
  int rn2 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
    while (rn2 == rn1) // this code checks for another value in the array if the number generated was previously selected
    {
        rn2 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
    }
    System.out.println("Computer's Value: " + rn2);
    // This code lets the computer select the third random number from your array       
  int rn3 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
    while (rn3 == rn1 || rn3 == rn2)
    {
        rn3 = boarduser[new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)];
    }
    System.out.println("Computer's Value: " + rn3);
    // turning the tokens chosen face down on the grid (changing their values to 0)
    {
        rn1 = 0;
        rn2 = 0;
        rn3 = 0;
    }
```

Basically I'm trying to have `rn1 = 0` set the random value generated from the array to 0, but when I print the array it seems the number still stays like it was. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rn1 = 0` is only changing `rn1`'s value locally, not in the actual array. You'll have to assign the element at the index from which you got `rn1` to 0 instead.

```
int rn1Index = new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length);
int rn1 = boarduser[rn1Index];
// ...
boarduser[rn1Index] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the random index into a variable and use it to "zerofy" that item in the array after it was read:

```
int index = new Random().nextInt(boarduser.length)
int rn1 = boarduser[index];
boarduser[index] = 0; // you need this line
```